# Advantages and Disadvantages of using System.out.printf();

Tags: java

I was just wondering what were the advantages and disadvantages of using `System.out.printf();` We normally use `System.out.println();` or `System.out.print();` but will it make a difference if we use `System.out.printf();`?  Is there a specific disadvantage or advantage to using `System.out.printf();` or any other print statements?

Thanks.

EDIT: Yes, I do know the difference between printf and println.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `printf()` and `print()`?

Comment: The alternative to using println() is to use a proper Logger.  Which print/println/printf you use doesn't matter.  Use the one is most appropriate for what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printf allows special formatting:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/sprintf/

That is the advantage.  Otherwise there is no disadvantage to calling print() as you do now.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) of the class PrintStream. There you can see that the print / println methods print a String and printf is

> - A convenience method to write a formatted string to this output stream
> - using the specified format string and arguments.