# Is Java's printf() a bad practice?

Tags: java, formatting, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantages and Disadvantages of using System.out.printf();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411584/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-system-out-printf)

In a discussion in an online forum, I was told that using `printf` method (like in `System.out.printf()`) was a bad practice and that I should use `println` instead, although the user couldn't give a clear explanation for that, it was something that "he was told". Is this true?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548249/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-printf-instead-of-print-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not true.

The only possible rationale I can think of is that `printf` with a literal `\n` and/or `\n` in the format string is going to produce platform specific line breaks ... which is a portability issue.  But the simple solution is to use `%n` in the format string.

Of course, using `printf` when no arguments need to be substituted into the format string is less than optimal.  I wouldn't say that this makes it Bad Practice though.

Comment: I read about that issue in Oracle's documentation about formatted printing and I already knew about it. But I think that is a matter of knowing the specifiers available and why one should use them. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

If you **need** the formatting capabilities of `printf`, then there's no question as `println` isn't an acceptable alternative.

If on the other hand you're just outputting a normal string, e.g.:

```
System.out.printf("All work completed.\n");
```

then it would be more canonical to use `println` for this.  In terms of program correctness it doesn't really matter - printf will probably be *marginally* more expensive to run but in reality this is not going to be relevant.

However, I did see some example code that used `printf` for simple output and I'll admit I found it confusing.  So I'd stick to `println` for that reason alone, that it will make your code more familiar and easier to understand for other developers.

(ETA: Even reviewing my own post now, I instinctively feel that the code sample is wrong and want to correct it to `println`.  So my earlier opinion definitely still holds.)

Answer (score 2):

`printf` can do things which `println` can't, so saying that you should *always* use `println` rather than `printf` obviously doesn't make sense.

For people who don't know the formatting specifiers used in `printf` control strings, they can be hard to read -- that might be the reason the person you talked to advised you not to use `printf`.

Some more general advice for next time: Remember there are a lot of people who will happily give you advice despite not knowing what they're talking about, and even among those who *do* know what they're talking about, there are as many opinions about programming as there are programmers. So you should *never* take anything as gospel just because someone told you or because you read it in a book. *Always* try to understand the reasons for the advice, and remember that there are exceptions to *every* rule. Understand that virtually every decision you make when designing or implementing a program has both pros and cons, so usually there is no one option which is unconditionally "right"; *you* have to use your experience and judgement to determine what is the "right" way to do things *in your current situation*, even if it might be "wrong" in most other cases.

Comment: I agree with you. As I am skeptic about these "dogmas" of coding and I've never heard of this one, I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Using either one is "bad" practice if you are doing it for debug logging.

If that is the case using a proper logging framework is the "best" practice. Java has plenty to pick from.

Comment: Where in the question it's told that it's purpose is logging?

Comment: it asks about bad practice, I give an example when this is ... just happens to be applicable to both alternatives